# Regex Negative Lookahead

Tags: asp.net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a situation wherein I need to search through a VS project for any  control that does not have a MaxLength property defined.

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text="Enter Name" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" MaxLength="25" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="MaxLength" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMisc" runat="server" Width="100" />
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for a regular expression pattern that will find the  controls that do not have a MaxLength defined?

My first attempt at this, which seems to work, seems imperfect at best...

```
<asp:TextBox.*?M(?!axLength=).*?/>
```

I would love to see a better solution.

*Note: the Visual Studio search chokes on my pattern above.  I was forced to use a different application to actually search using this pattern*

Comment: There won’t be a good solution using regular expressions. Why not parse the code using an XML parser and use XPath? Much easier, much more reliable.

Comment: @Konrad: Good idea, another alternative would be to create an XML schema that requires that attribute and validate all the files against the schema.

Comment: Actually @Konrad, there turned out to be a very good solution using regex and I can search through my VS project right within VS and not have to open up a 3rd party xml parser.  The VS specific pattern \<asp\:TextBox(~(MaxLength=)[^\>])*/\> works fast and flawlessly (see the other answers to this thread).

Comment: If that works – very good. But beware that this pattern will fail to find many special cases (which might not be a problem for you), e.g. `<asp:TextBox Text="MaxLength=" />` – clearly you would want to find this, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying for:

```
<asp:TextBox(?:(?!MaxLength=|>).)*/>
```

The `.` consumes one character at a time, but only after the lookahead has determined that it's not `>` or the beginning of `MaxLength=`.  Note that you *must* exclude `>` in the lookahead, or it will keep looking for `MaxLength=` beyond the end of the current element.  For example, when applied to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMisc" /><asp:TextBox MaxLength="50" />
```

...you want it to match the first tag, but it doesn't because the lookahead sees `MaxLength=` in the second element.  A non-greedy quantifier like `.*?` will not prevent that from happening.  It might *seem* like it's working correctly, but that's only because the tags usually appear on separate lines, and the `.` doesn't match newlines.

The Visual Studio version would be:

```
\<asp\:TextBox(~(MaxLength=|\>).)*/\>
```

`<`, `>` and `:` all have special meanings in VS regexes and have to be escaped, and `~(...)` is the VS syntax for a negative lookahead.

Comment: +1 But the alternation in the negative lookahead is unnecessary if you Use a `[^>]` instead of a dot like so: `<asp:TextBox(?:(?!MaxLength)[^>])*/>` This is a bit more efficient for both matches and non-matches. Just sayin'... 8^)

Comment: @ridge: Yeah, but I went with this way because I think it's a little easier to read for someone who's not familiar with the technique.  More seriously, I left the `=` off, so it incorrectly matched the tag that happened to have `MaxLength` in an attribute *value*, not just tags with an attribute *named* `MaxLength`.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks guys!  This solution works perfectly and is quite adaptable.  I was completely unaware of these differences in the VS regex syntax, so that is an extra bonus.  I found that the use of the [^>] was noticeably faster.  My final adaptation was \<asp\:TextBox(~(MaxLength=)[^\>])*/\>  I cannot express how much time this has saved me and how grateful I am to your insight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... negative lookahead on "MaxLength" within the element

```
\<(?!.*MaxLength[^/>]*)[^/>]*/\>
```